# EntityAlreadyExists: Role with name chatbot-andrea-executor already exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, claudiajs

I am creating a Nodebot with claudiajs.

```
const botBuilder = require('claudia-bot-builder')
const excuse     = require('huh')

module.exports = botBuilder((req) => {
    return `Thanks for sending ${req.text}. Your message is very important to us, but ${excuse.get()}`
})
```

but when I am deploying to aws cloud.

```
claudia create --region us-east-1 --api-module app
```

I am getting this error:

```
{ EntityAlreadyExists: Role with name chatbot-andrea-executor already exists.
    at Request.extractError (/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/claudia/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:47:29)
    at Request.callListeners (/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/claudia/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/claudia/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/claudia/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:678:14)
    at Request.transition (/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/claudia/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/claudia/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/claudia/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/claudia/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/claudia/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:680:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/claudia/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
  message: 'Role with name chatbot-andrea-executor already exists.',
  code: 'EntityAlreadyExists',
  time: 2017-05-19T19:03:01.956Z,
  requestId: '-requestId (I changed it)-',
  statusCode: 409,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 4.143280988568199 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just find that even (if you need to) you can set the role in the deployment command:

```
claudia create --region us-east-1 --role chatbot-andrea-executor  --api-module app
```

You have to replace the name on collision after **--role**'s flag. Also you are more curios about [here](https://github.com/claudiajs/claudia/blob/master/docs/create.md) is a good starting point about custom deployments.

Answer (score 4):

As it is very clever, there is a role in aws that has the same name. So, you can try to change the name of the role in your code but how we are using a prebuilt Nodebot solution we have not too much choices. So, delete the role is the answer.

1. go to [IAM management console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-west-2#/roles)
2. Delete the role

[image]

You can find more info about this name collision, [here](https://github.com/claudiajs/claudia/issues/9).

Answer (score 3):

For me, the issue was the app was already deployed to aws lambda and I already have a facebook bot.

I wanted to create a telegram bot and that's why the issue happened.

Then, I used `update` rather than `create` like:

```
claudia update --region us-central-1 --api-module bot --configure-telegram-bot
```

and it worked for me,